# Hiding Google Analytics code based on theme options

Tags: functions, theme-options, google-analytics

I'm doing up a WordPress theme at the moment, and I want users to be able to add Google Analytics to their site by just adding their tracking code -- you know, the `UA-20149670-1` -type number thing.

At the moment I have all the Google Analytics JavaScript code sitting in the `<head>` of my pages, with the tracking code being set by the user via a theme option text input form.

However, if the user *doesn't* add a tracking code, then all the Google JavaScript is still left sitting in the `<head>`, without a tracking code, bloating up the header.

How can I code this so that the Google Analytics code only appears after the user puts in their tracking code?

Additionally, at the moment the Google Analytics code is all still in `header.php` -- ideally I'd like to move it instead to `functions.php`. How best would I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Could we see how your code currently looks, just the code that deals with output for GA, you should only need a simple IF condition around the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the GA code from your header and wrap it in a function hooked to `wp_head`;

```
function __analytics_head()
{
    $options = get_option( 'themename_theme_options' );
    if ( !empty( $options['analytics'] ) ) :
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<?php echo esc_js( $options['analytics'] ) ; ?>']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_head', '__analytics_head', 100 );
```

Obviously, this is only guideline code - the way you retrieve your options may vary - but the idea is to check if a GA account has been set, and if so, proceed to print the script.

Comment: Hi TheDeadMedic, thanks for this. I gave it a go and unfortunately it doesn't work at the moment: WordPress chokes on it and only loads the stuff before it in the <head>, then stops dead. I have very little PHP knowledge, so I didn't really know what, if anything, to do next, but maybe you or someone else here could have a go at updating this? It certainly seems like it's along the right lines for what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I have revised my answer with a more concise solution. It was most likely choking as you hadn't swapped out my example function `get_my_theme_option()` with a valid one. For now I have resorted to `get_option()`.

Comment: Thanks again. It's still not really working, but I think we're _almost_ there... :)

I'm using the [Themeshaper sample theme options page](http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options/) and usually getting stuff like this:

`$options = get_option('themename_theme_options'); echo $options['analytics'];` -- does that imply any changes for your code?

Comment: Revised answer again.

Comment: And we're working. :)

Thankyou, TheDeadMedic!

Answer (score -5):

on a sidenote; the Analytics code should be sitting in the footer...

Comment: That is wrong. Google changed there code about a year ago to asynchronous script so it should go inside the head tag

Comment: from Google Analytics Help:

"...Once you find the code snippet, copy and paste it into the bottom of your content, immediately before the </body> tag of each page you are planning to track..."

Comment: As @Bainternet said, for asynchronous (the latest), it's `</head>` - http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=174090

Comment: Hey @stffn, this would be better left as a comment on the question because it doesn't directly answer the question.